# SSLCertificateChainFile is obsolete

Tags: apache, ssl, mod-ssl

I'm on Apache 2.4.12, so [SSLCertificateChainFile](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslcertificatechainfile) is now obsolete, and any intermediate certificates are supposed to be included in the server certificate file. I cannot figure out how to do this, however--any combination of certificates other than *only* the site certificate inside the specified file causes an invalid key error. How do I properly include the intermediate certificate inside the file that I specify using [SSLCertificateFile](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslcertificatefile)?

Comment: [SSLCertificateChainFile Deprecation Warning on Apache 2.4.8+](http://serverfault.com/q/588986/217116)

Answer (score 12):

Taken from the Apache 2.4 Module `mod_ssl` documentation:

> > [`SSLCertificateFile`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslcertificatefile) Directive
>
> The files may also include intermediate CA certificates, sorted from leaf to root. This is supported with version 2.4.8 and later, and obsoletes [`SSLCertificateChainFile`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslcertificatechainfile).

What this means is that the `SSLCertificateFile` directive now (after 2.4.8) accepts files with a full certificate chain (from leaf to root). If you have your server certificate in `domain.crt` and the CA chain file in `domain-ca.crt`, you'd need to concatenate both files *from leaf to root*, i.e. starting with your server certificate, as in

```
cat domain.crt domain-ca.crt > bundle.crt
```

and use that file inside your site's `conf` file:

```
SSLCertificateFile      /path/to/bundle.crt
```

(For example, using Ubuntu default path, these files will be stored at `/etc/apache2/ssl/`.)

Comment: That's indeed the correct solution: aggregate the `.crt` + `ca_bundle.crt`, and use it as `SSLCertificateFile`.

Answer (score 6):

For Apache 2.4.8, `SSLCertificateChainFile` has been made obsolete. However, **it's just deprecated and not removed**, so you may continue to use the older style. However, for Apache versions > 2.4.8, `SSLCertificateChainFile` will not work.

> **SSLCertificateChainFile is deprecated**
>
> SSLCertificateChainFile became obsolete with version 2.4.8, when
>   SSLCertificateFile was extended to also load intermediate CA
>   certificates from the server certificate file
>
> **source**: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_ssl.html#SSLCertificateChainFile

**Old Style (Valid on Apache <= 2.4.8)**

```
#SSL Directives
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/<mydomain.com>.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/<mydomain.com>.key
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/certs/<full-chain-bundle>.crt
```

**source:** [How to Install an SSL Certificate on Apache](https://codesport.io/lamp-stack-advanced/creating-ssl-certificates-for-multi-domain-v-hosts/#vhost-config)

**New Style (Valid on Apache >= 2.4.8)**

```
#SSL Directives
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/<full-chain-bundle>.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/<mydomain.com>.key
```

**source:** https://codesport.io/lamp-stack-advanced/lets-encrypt-tutorial/#vhost-config

Comment: Didn't work for me.  I removed the <mydomain.com>.crt and then the error messages indicated the certificate and key didn't match.

Comment: I think what makes this answer a little confusing is that `<full-chain-bundle>.crt` appears in both the old and new configuration. If I'm not mistaken, in the old configuration only the *CA chain* would appear in the file called to by `SSLCertificateChainFile`, whereas in the new configuration the CA chain should be appended to the server certificate, into a *full chain*, which is called to by `SSLCertificateFile`. I attempted to clarify that in my answer.

Comment: @JonathanY. is right: you have to merge the domain.crt + chain.crt into a bundle.crt, and then use it as `SSLCertificateFile` in place. It's not sufficient to only use the `<full-chain-bundle>.crt` alone, which is what this answer suggests!

Comment: I'm running 2.4.38-3+deb10u7 and the `SSLCertificateChainFile` trumped the intermediate in the `SSLCertificateFile`